# GAE app access to closed server behind firewall

Tags: google-app-engine, firewall

I have an application on google app engine servers and private master server behind firewall. Accesss to master server closed by default. So I want to open access for my GAE app. Application sends by XML-RPC requests to master server. How can I do what? How to add GAE servers to my firewall access list?

Comment: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html#Secure_Data_Connection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html#Secure_Data_Connection:

"Your application can connect to systems behind your company's firewall using the Google [Secure Data Connector](https://developers.google.com/secure-data-connector/) (SDC). With the SDC Agent set up on your network, App Engine applications running on your Google Apps domain can authenticate with the Agent and access URLs on your intranet. The SDC Agent ensures that only your applications can connect to your intranet, and that they will do so only for users signed in using an Apps account on your domain."

Comment: What if I cannot force my client to use SDC?

Answer (score -1):

If not for GAE, you could use Reverse Port Forwarding Wizard:
http://www.upredsun.com/reverse-port-forwarding/reverse-port-forwarding.html

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question.